Power BI admin - Guest users can access Microsoft Fabric vs Guest users can browse and access Fabric content?
Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/enterprise/service-admin-azure-ad-b2b#admin-info-for-b2b-collaboration
Guest users can access Microsoft Fabric

When you turn on this setting, Microsoft Entra Business-to-Business
(Microsoft Entra B2B) guest users can access Fabric. If you turn off
this setting, B2B guest users receive an error when trying to access
Fabric and any Fabric items they have permissions to. Disabling this
setting for the entire organization also prevents users from inviting
guests to your organization. Use the specific security groups option
to control which B2B guest users can access Fabric.

Guest users can browse and access Fabric content

This setting allows Microsoft Entra B2B guest users to have full
access to the browsing experience using the left-hand navigation pane
in the organization. Guest users who have been assigned workspace
roles or specific item permissions continue to have those roles and/or
permissions, even if this setting is disabled.

Please can someone explain the practical meaning between these with a simple example.
For example - suppose I have assigned workspace viewer role to a guest user. Now if 1st option is enabled, and 2nd option is disabled (which means user cannot see the navigation pane), then how will the user access the workspace?

A very simple example :
If a guest user has a Viewer role in a workspace:

With the first setting enabled and the second setting disabled, they cannot browse Fabric but can still access the workspace through a direct link.
If the first setting is disabled, they won’t be able to access Fabric at all, even if they have a direct link.

